# How to hide this button with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to hide the button below using:
$("i.fa fa-search").hide();
but nothing I try hides the button.

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">
::before == $0
</i>
</button>
```

How can I hide the button above using JQuery?

Comment: Use  ̀$("i.fa.fa-search")`

Comment: Thanks - it worked!

Comment: It wont hide the button it will hide the <i> tag alone. To hide that button alone, set Id to that button and pass that id in the selector.